# How to pass data within "export default" to outside of export default Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, web-deployment

I got my API data store in `carcount` for sure, but I can't use that `carcount` in `const` outside the export default, any suggestion please?

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      carcount: [],
    };
  },
  Create() {
    axios
      .get("http://www.mustavi.com/TotalVehicles/?param1=2020-09-04")
      .then((res) => {
        this.carcount = res.data.data.carCount;
      });
  },
};

const totalcar = this.carcount
```

I do it this way be cause I have to export the whole const as below

```
const locationData = [
  {
    value: totalcar,
    name: 'Car'
  }
];

export {
  locationData,
};
```

Comment: What is the external environment? Where do you want to pass data from the component?

Comment: my bad, just outside of export default

Comment: The `carcount` data belongs to that component instance. If you want to access it externally then you will need a reference to that particular component instance. `this.carcount` doesn't make sense – what instance is `this` referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Vue components are not designed for this. If you need to pass data to another component use events or vuex for state management.

```
export default {
  Create() {
    axios
      .get("http://www.mustavi.com/TotalVehicles/?param1=2020-09-04")
      .then((res) => {
        this.$emit('carcount', {
          value: res.data.data.carCount,
          name: 'Car'
        });
      });
  },
};
```